# Backtick character not working on Windows 8.1

Tags: keyboard, boot-camp, windows-8.1

I'm not sure if it's always been this way or not but for some reason any time I hit the backtick key I'm actually getting a backslash character instead (and amusingly when I hit shift + backtick i get the pipe character as well).

When I switch over to OSX, the backtick character works fine. I only installed 8.1 a few days ago so I really don't know if it was never worked or if this is something new. Any ideas on how to resolve or how to troubleshoot this issue?

When typing the key into SharpKeys it's telling me "unknown 0x0056"

Here's my setup:
Windows 8.1 x64

Apple Macbook Pro Retina (mid-2013)

Bootcamp drivers are installed

US English qwerty layout

Comment: What language packs do you have installed?  What version of the Bootcamp drivers do you have insalled?  What version of OS X.  This could be a Bootcamp driver capability issue because of the change from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1

Comment: Bootcamp 5.0.5411, still researching language packs, but I haven't installed any myself, this should be stock 8.1

Comment: The reason I asked is because you mention your using the US English keyboard layout.  Most people woudln't mention that if they were both English speaking and in the US.  If you simply installed Windows 8.1 and your language is English its unlikely you have any language packs instaleld.  The base language isn't included in any language pack numbers.

Comment: Yeah I will have to go figure out what language packs are installed. The only reason I specified it that language settings came up when I searched keyboard.

Comment: So when I go to `Time and language > Region and language` underneath languages is just `English (United States)` so I would assume that means only one language is installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the current version of bootcamp drivers is the cause of this.

You can [work around this issue](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23604395#23604395) by changing the input method to "United States International - Apple"